# PowerShell to download a file with dynamic size via an indirect php link (by Invoke-WebRequest or COM object)

Tags: powershell, download

I'm working on create an script to download log file from an application automatically.

I managed to work out the login with Invoke-WebRequest but stuck on the download. The log download link is provided by the appliance on the web page:
https://some.thing.com/common/download_logs.php

If I click on the link, a file with the identical name will be downloaded (kbox_logs.tgz). But I'm not able to figure out how to do it via Invoke-WebRequest.

When I do something like below, based on WireShark, I'll be kick back to the logon page (welcome.php) and re-direct to the main page (summary.php).

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://some.thing.com/adminui/settings_support.php") -WebSession $ms -Method POST
```

I compared the package between direct access to download.php (after logon) and navigate through the site. The only difference in the HTTP header is an referer attribute. So I build the header manually as below (cookie info are from session variable so they are valid) and I got a different result: I got login page.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
User-Agent                     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063
Host                           some.thing.com
cookie                         kboxid=97d0e93e002f4846ef9211d013f4b261; KACE_CSRF_TOKEN=aad3f8c254d2f25bd24e35c51d654541822080da825d6353937a7fe294216089689cc68480299b657f4fb1e9be77ac711a658a96e2df50ffc5e242b94bd9baf4
Accept-Encoding                gzip, deflate
Referer                        http://some.thing.com/adminui/settings_support.php
accept                         text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Accept-Language                en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-Hans-CN;q=0.5,zh-Hans;q=0.3
```

Not sure if I got the header right.

==============================

I tried COM object approach as well. There are two last steps in front of me:

1, Click the download link (silly me, I can only navigate, can't download. Click() method is reported not exist. The way I used in logon page doesn't work here.)

2, Save the file (I want to run the whole thing in the background so sending hotkey 'S' is not very ideal).

Here's the code:

```
$username ="user"
$password ='pass'

$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"

$init_url = "http://some.thing.com/adminui/welcome.php"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.silent = $true
$ie.navigate($init_url)

while ($ie.busy -eq $true) {start-sleep 1}

$textbox_name = $ie.Document.getElementsBytagName("INPUT")|where {$_.name -eq 'LOGIN_name'}
$textbox_password = $ie.Document.getElementsBytagName("INPUT")|where {$_.name -eq 'LOGIN_PASSWORD'}
$button_login = $ie.Document.getElementsBytagName("BUTTON")

$textbox_name.value = $username
$textbox_password.value = $password
$button_login.item().click()

$setting_url = "http://some.thing.com/adminui/settings_control_panel.php"
$ie.navigate($setting_url)
while ($ie.busy -eq $true) {start-sleep 1}
$support_url = "http://some.thing.com/adminui/settings_support.php"
$ie.navigate($support_url)
while ($ie.busy -eq $true) {start-sleep 1}

$ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")|where {$_.innertext -eq 'Retrieve appliance activity logs'}.item.click()
enter code here
```

Comment: Maybe [this blog](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell) can help you. It describes three methods for downloading files using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by taking a look at the forms and methods on the page:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://some.thing.com/adminui/settings_support.php").Forms
```

This should hopefully give you some information about the download_logs Action.

Can you locate a direct url to the file you are trying to download? Perhaps then you can point your `Invoke-WebRequest` at the file and provide an `-OutFile` path. Maybe you can locate this through the 'Top-level HTML view'?

If you know what the header you need to supply is, you can try this:

```
$headers = @{"name"="value"}  
$uri = "https://some.thing.com/adminui/settings_support.php"
$outpath = "$PSScriptRoot\kbox_logs.tgz"

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $uri -Method POST -OutFile $outpath
```

Comment: The setting_support.php has two forms. Form[0] doesn't have action. Form[1] has an action /adminui/search.php

Comment: I tried you suggestion to attach an outfile parameter. Only got a logon page like I updated in my post.